# JMeter - some functions can't be executed in Function Helper

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

About JMeter Function Helper Dialog, It's a great tool, but some functions can't be executed using it when expecting variables to be available

[__split](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__split) function have mandatory variable name throws exception for example when calling `${__split(a,a,)}`

[image]

Also function [__isVarDefined](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__isVarDefined) gets a NullPointerException:

```
2018-02-12 08:03:20,603 ERROR o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error calling function ${__split(a,a,)}
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.UnmodifiableJMeterVariables.put(UnmodifiableJMeterVariables.java:73) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.SplitFunction.execute(SplitFunction.java:99) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:137) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.gui.FunctionHelper.actionPerformed(FunctionHelper.java:200) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
```

Also new function [__isVarDefined](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__isVarDefined) from JMeter 4 gets a NullPointerException:

```
2018-02-11 10:32:38,093 ERROR o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error calling function ${__isVarDefined(a)}
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.IsVarDefined.execute(IsVarDefined.java:53) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:137) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.gui.FunctionHelper.actionPerformed(FunctionHelper.java:200) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_25]
```

Should JMeter initialize variables in Function Helpers or is it irrelevant and therefore need to add a warning that it's unavailable without variable context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions that are usually not testable in Function Helper Dialog require some context:

- Properties set
- Variables set
  ...

This is a limitation identified under following enhancement:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61834

Feel free to contribute a patch if you have some idea, an example would be:

- An empty JMeterVariable could be created
- A Text Area where user can input some Groovy Code to fill in this object or other properties

This way any function could be testable.